# MySQL join query not using Indexes?

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS `numrows` 
FROM (`tbl_A`) 
JOIN `tbl_B` ON `tbl_A`.`B_id` = `tbl_B`.`id` 
WHERE 
    `tbl_B`.`boolean_value` <> 1;
```

I added three indexes for `tbl_A`.`B_id`, `tbl_B`.`id` and `tbl_B`.`boolean_value` but mysql still says it doesn't use indexes (in queries not using indexes log) and it examine whole of tables to retrieve the result.

I need to know what I should do to optimize this query.

**EDIT:**

Explain output:

```
id  select_type table  type  possible_keys          key   key_len  ref      rows  Extra 
1    SIMPLE     tbl_B  ALL   PRIMARY,boolean_value  NULL  NULL     NULL     5049  Using where
1    SIMPLE     tbl_A  ref   B_id                   B_id  9        tbl_B.id 9     Using where; Using index
```

Comment: PLease show us the explain plan of this query

Comment: by writing `DESCRIBE ` before the query

Comment: @PugganSe do you have doubt that indexes are exists? To show running-plan keyword `EXPLAIN` is using.

Comment: @triclosan or i just forgot that `EXPLAIN` and `DESCRIBE` shows the same output, and i more used to using `DESCRIBE`

Comment: EXPLAIN says:  
    `id select_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows Extra   
    1 SIMPLE tbl_B ALL PRIMARY,boolean_value NULL NULL NULL 5049 Using where   
    1 SIMPLE tbl_A ref B_id B_id 9 tbl_B.id 9 Using where; Using index`

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with markdown here. 

It seems Expalin says it uses indexes but in log file mysql says it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The explain show us that an index is used to make the join to tbl_B but no index is used to filter tbl_A on the boolean value.

An index was available but the engine choose not to use it. Why it happen:

- maybe 5049 rows is not a big deal and the engine saw that using the index to filter something like 10% of the rows using the index **would be as fast as doing it without using it**.
- Booleans takes only 3 values: 1, 0 or NULL. So the **cardinality of the index will always be very low** (3 max). Low cardinality index are usually dropped by the query analyser (which is quite right usually thinking this index won't help him a lot)

It would be interesting to see if the query analyser behaves the same way when you have a 50/50 repartition of true and false value for this boolean, or when you have just a few False.

Now usually boolean fields are useful only on indexes containing multiple keys, so that if your queries use all the fields of the index (in where or order by) the query analyser will trust that index to be really a good tool.

Note that indexes are slowing down your writes and takes extra-spaces, do not add useless indexes. Using logt-query-not-using-indexes is a good thing, but you should **compensate that log information with the slow queries log**.If the query is fast it's not a problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. I removed WHERE clause and boolean_value, but it is still in the log file. I forget to tell I have ORDER BY and LIMIT in my query. I think they are the main problem. The query is like this now:
`SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS numrows
FROM (tbl_A) 
JOIN tbl_B ON tbl_A.B_id = tbl_B.id
ORDER BY tbl_A.id DESC
LIMIT 0, 10;`

Comment: This is Explain: `id select_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows Extra
1 SIMPLE tbl_A index B_id PRIMARY 8 NULL 100 
1 SIMPLE tbl_B eq_ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 8 tbl_A.B_id 1 Using where; Using index`

Comment: Sorry I don't know how i can place the codes in markdowns like you :(

Comment: If you are odering on tblA.id you NEED an index on tblA.id.

Answer (score 0):

if `boolean_value` it's really boolean value indexing of it not so good idea. Index wouldn't be effective.